# Fragments, How to Navigate back to the previous Fragment, from the current Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using Fragment A,Fragment B .. and so on. i want to navigate back to the previous Fragment, from the current Fragment.

I want to use **Back Button in Mobile** to get back navigation. 
 How can i do this ? OR i have to make **Back** button in layout xml.

i tried below code,

```
fTransaction.add(R.id.container, nF).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

when i pressed **Back Button in Mobile** , it restarts the App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go back to previous fragment using phone's back button you should override `onKeyDown()` mehtod.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fTransaction.addToBackStack(null).add(R.id.container, nF).commit();
```

Comment: Please add a plain-English explanation of how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When replacing a fragment use `replace` instead of `add` and then `addToBackStack`:

```
fTransaction.replace(R.id.container, nF).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```